# switch with while loop won't end when told to

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have two methods, `getOption()` and `driver()`.

`getOption()` takes a String from a scanner, breaks it into individual words, and returns an array of Strings.

`driver()` then gets the first value of that array, getOption()[0], and begins a while loop based on that first String. While the String does not equal "quit", check if the value matches any switch case. However, when I run it, it can do any of the switch cases, but the quit statement never works. Can anyone give me a hand?

```
public String[] getOption(){
    String optionLine[];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input string\n");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    optionLine = line.split(" ");
    return optionLine;
}

public void driver(){
    String option = getOption()[0];
    Stats s = new Stats(data);
    while (!"quit".equals(option)){
    switch (option) {
        case "add": //data.put(getOption()[1], getValues());
                    System.out.println("add");
                    break;
        case "set": System.out.println("set");
                    break;
        case "print": System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
                      break;
        case "sum": System.out.println(s.sum());
                    break;
        case "mean": System.out.println(s.mean());
                     break;
        case "stdev": System.out.println(s.standardDeviation());
                      break;
        case "median": System.out.println(s.median());
                       break;
        case "primes": System.out.println(s.primes());
                       break;
        case "summary": System.out.println("summary");
                        break;
          //case "test": System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getValues()));
    }
    driver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling recursively at the end of your while loop the method `driver();`

no matter if you read `getOption` or not, you are still coming back inside the method...

that is the reason of the apparently not working while condition...

a very unusual pitfall.

Comment: I'm very inexperienced, this is an assignment. What do you suggest I do instead? I apologize for being so lost :(

Comment: at the end of the while remove the call to driver() again, instead read again the option = getOption()[0]; and the s = new Stats(data);

Answer (score 1):

Once you get into your `While` loop, you never change the value of option.  You could change your while to be

```
while (true){ 
option = getOption()[0];
Stats s = new Stats(data);
    switch (option) {
    case "add": //data.put(getOption()[1], getValues());
                System.out.println("add");
                break;
    case "set": System.out.println("set");
                break;
    case "print": System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
                  break;
    case "sum": System.out.println(s.sum());
                break;
    case "mean": System.out.println(s.mean());
                 break;
    case "stdev": System.out.println(s.standardDeviation());
                  break;
    case "median": System.out.println(s.median());
                   break;
    case "primes": System.out.println(s.primes());
                   break;
    case "summary": System.out.println("summary");
                    break;
      //case "test": System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getValues()));
    case "quit":  break;

    }
}
```

Note, if you use my answer, you will need to no longer recursively call `driver()`.

Comment: I fear, this won't help since he enters a new while-loop in the recursive `driver()` call

Comment: Okay, I replaced option with getOption()[0], I appreciate the suggestion. I also replaced option in the switch statement with getOption()[0] as well. Now only a few of my switch statements work, but quit works if I write it twice... any explanation? I feel like I'm missing something big.

Comment: I dropped the driver() call, it still does the same thing. I need to call the switch statement or quit statement twice for it to work.

Comment: Ah... Try removing the `[0]` from the `getOption` call.

Comment: You may have to make the return type to `String` instead of `String[]`.  Do you have a reason to use `String[]`?

Comment: The getOption() method breaks a string of multiple words into individual words in an array. I need this because we will be adding data to a map in the future which requires a key and value, so multiple inputs will be required.

Comment: Wish my account could use chat... either way, it doesn't work properly yet. I need to enter the command twice for it to work. I have getOption()[0] in the while loop condition as you suggested.

Comment: Fixed it with Xoce and Filkolev's comments. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be changing the value of `option` anywhere. You're calling `driver()` recursively, but that doesn't affect the local variable in the currently executing method which stays the same.

So, one `driver()` method calls another, which creates its own `option` variable, unrelated to the `option` variable of the caller. Basically, only the innermost call to `driver()` will ever return and you'll be stuck in the `while` loop of its caller.

Get rid of that recursion, it's unnecessary. Under the `switch` just call `getOption()` and update the value of `option`.

```
while (!"quit".equals(option)){
  // switch statement

  option = getOption()[0];     
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right... if I define option below the beginning of the loop, the while loop cannot find it.

Comment: I just pasted a fragment, as you can see option is not declared here, just assigned. The declaration is still there, above the while loop.